# Highlight background color in specific pages

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have 2 activities in my app. I navigate between them using a NavigationDrawer.

Activity A is "Mes cours" and Activity B is "Mes branches".

When I'm on Activity A, I'd like to change the background of the item "Mes cours", so the user knows that he's in that page. 
But if I'm in Activity B, I'd like to change the background of "Mes branches".

Everything works fine, but I want to solve that problem of changing the background...

I'm using the same menu for those 2 pages. How can I do it so ?

Thank you guys.Tell me if you need more code.

My menu.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_navigation">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mes_cours"
        android:title="Mes cours"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mes_branches"
        android:title="Mes branches"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by using

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

Here `getItem(0)` refers to 1st item, so for 2nd item change it to `getItem(1)`

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: That's good enough ! At least it changes the color ! Thank you !

Comment: Dont forget to rate up the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
 <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
```

to your following code after menu, like written under

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mes_cours"
        android:title="Mes cours"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mes_branches"
        android:title="Mes branches"/>


    </group>



</menu>
```